# Django - Using jQuery/AJAX to access database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I hope someone can help as I have attempted this multiple times had had very little success. I have attempted to use the tango with django book to adapt it to this situation and done the same with many other examples online but had no luck. Anyway...

I am currently designing a small 'Fake News' website with Django which has a mini game that displays a news article (Title, description, picture) to the user and they have to vote whether it is 'Fact' or 'Fiction', they are then told whether they are correct and how many people have voted for that answer previously.

I have it working completely fine if I have all the data stored in a javascript variable like this:

```
    var questions = [
    ["Pope Francis Shocks World, Endorses Donald Trump for President, Releases Statement", 
    "News outlets around the world are reporting on the news that Pope Francis has made the unprecedented decision to endorse a US presidential candidate. His statement in support of Donald Trump was released from the Vatican this evening: 'I have been hesitant to offer any kind of support for either candidate in the US presidential election but I now feel that to not voice my concern would be a dereliction of my duty as the Holy See...",
    "fake", 7, 15, '../../static/images/popetrump.jpg'],
    ["Trump Offering Free One-Way Tickets to Africa & Mexico for Those Who Wanna Leave America", 
    "President elect Donald Trump has sensationally offered free one-way tickets to Mexico or Africa for anyone who wants to leave America in the aftermath of his election victory. The extraordinary, and highly controversial, offer was revealed by an aid at a press conference in New York this morning...",
    "fake", 13, 17, '../../static/images/TrumpTickets.jpg'],
    ["Feral pig drinks 18 cans of beer, fights cow and then passes out drunk under tree", 
    "The swine drank 18 beers on its bender in Port Hedland, Western Australia, according to ABC News. The alcohol also made the pig hungry and was seen looking through rubbish bags for something to eat...",
    "true", 8, 19, '../../static/images/pig.jpg'],
    ["Cinnamon Roll Can Explodes Inside Man's Butt During Shoplifting Incident", 
    "Las Vegas – Martin Klein, 41 of Las Vegas, was arrested after a shopping lifting incident turned horribly wrong. According to reports, Mr. Klein and his partner, Jerry Weis, had stolen several grocery items from the Las Vegas Walmart...",
    "fake", 19, 7, '../../static/images/CinnamonRollMan.jpg'],
    ["Poll: 38% of Florida voters believe Ted Cruz could be the Zodiac Killer", 
    "While a 62 percent majority of voters answered 'No' when asked if they believed Cruz was responsible for the string of murders in the early 70s, 10 percent answered 'Yes' and an additional 28 percent said they were unsure...",
    "true", 11, 6, '../../static/images/FloridaPoll.jpg'],
    ["Hamster resurrection: Pet rises from the grave at Easter after being buried in garden", 
    "Tink the hamster was found ‘cold and lifeless’ in the bottom of her cage and laid to rest by a couple who were looking after her for a friend. But the next day the rodent – who was not dead but hibernating – reappeared as perplexed Les Kilbourne-Smith crushed a pile of old boxes for recycling...",
    "true", 15, 9, '../../static/images/hamster.jpg'],
]
```

I have been able to add all the articles to the database however I am unsure how to extract the data from the database as I need it and update the number of fact and fiction votes as more people play the game. From reading online I believe I need to use AJAX to do this but I honest have no idea where to start from in order to display a new article every time the next button is pressed, update the number of votes etc.

Hopefully someone can at least point me in the right direction and I will post all the code I have so far and think might be relevant below.

game.js:

```
 var questions = [
    ["Pope Francis Shocks World, Endorses Donald Trump for President, Releases Statement", 
    "News outlets around the world are reporting on the news that Pope Francis has made the unprecedented decision to endorse a US presidential candidate. His statement in support of Donald Trump was released from the Vatican this evening: 'I have been hesitant to offer any kind of support for either candidate in the US presidential election but I now feel that to not voice my concern would be a dereliction of my duty as the Holy See...",
    "fake", 7, 15, '../../static/images/popetrump.jpg'],
    ["Trump Offering Free One-Way Tickets to Africa & Mexico for Those Who Wanna Leave America", 
    "President elect Donald Trump has sensationally offered free one-way tickets to Mexico or Africa for anyone who wants to leave America in the aftermath of his election victory. The extraordinary, and highly controversial, offer was revealed by an aid at a press conference in New York this morning...",
    "fake", 13, 17, '../../static/images/TrumpTickets.jpg'],
    ["Feral pig drinks 18 cans of beer, fights cow and then passes out drunk under tree", 
    "The swine drank 18 beers on its bender in Port Hedland, Western Australia, according to ABC News. The alcohol also made the pig hungry and was seen looking through rubbish bags for something to eat...",
    "true", 8, 19, '../../static/images/pig.jpg'],
    ["Cinnamon Roll Can Explodes Inside Man's Butt During Shoplifting Incident", 
    "Las Vegas – Martin Klein, 41 of Las Vegas, was arrested after a shopping lifting incident turned horribly wrong. According to reports, Mr. Klein and his partner, Jerry Weis, had stolen several grocery items from the Las Vegas Walmart...",
    "fake", 19, 7, '../../static/images/CinnamonRollMan.jpg'],
    ["Poll: 38% of Florida voters believe Ted Cruz could be the Zodiac Killer", 
    "While a 62 percent majority of voters answered 'No' when asked if they believed Cruz was responsible for the string of murders in the early 70s, 10 percent answered 'Yes' and an additional 28 percent said they were unsure...",
    "true", 11, 6, '../../static/images/FloridaPoll.jpg'],
    ["Hamster resurrection: Pet rises from the grave at Easter after being buried in garden", 
    "Tink the hamster was found ‘cold and lifeless’ in the bottom of her cage and laid to rest by a couple who were looking after her for a friend. But the next day the rodent – who was not dead but hibernating – reappeared as perplexed Les Kilbourne-Smith crushed a pile of old boxes for recycling...",
    "true", 15, 9, '../../static/images/hamster.jpg'],
]

var questionCount = 0;
var correctAnswer = 0;


$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#answer").hide();
        $("#game_home").hide();
        $("#game_title").html(questions[questionCount][0]);
        $("#game_description").html(questions[questionCount][1]);
        $("#game_picture").attr('src', questions[questionCount][5]);
        $("#game_fact").click(function() {

            $("#game_picture").hide();
            $("#game_fact").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#game_fiction").prop('disabled', true);
            if(questions[questionCount][2] == "true"){
                $("#your_answer").html("Correct! This story is a Fact!");
                $("#current_answer_fact").html("Fact: " + (((questions[questionCount][3])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                $("#current_answer_fiction").html("Fiction: " + (((questions[questionCount][4])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                questions[questionCount][3] = questions[questionCount][3]+1;
                correctAnswer += 1;
            }
            else{
                $("#your_answer").html("Incorrect! This story is actually Fiction!");
                $("#current_answer_fact").html("Fact: " + (((questions[questionCount][3])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                $("#current_answer_fiction").html("Fiction: " + (((questions[questionCount][4])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                questions[questionCount][3] = questions[questionCount][3]+1
            }
            $("#answer").show();
        });
        $("#game_fiction").click(function() {
            $("#game_picture").hide();
            $("#game_fact").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#game_fiction").prop('disabled', true);
            if(questions[questionCount][2] == "fake"){
                $("#your_answer").html("Correct! This story is Fiction!");
                $("#current_answer_fact").html("Fact: " + (((questions[questionCount][3])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                $("#current_answer_fiction").html("Fiction: " + (((questions[questionCount][4])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                questions[questionCount][3] = questions[questionCount][4]+1
                correctAnswer += 1;
            }
            else{
                $("#your_answer").html("Incorrect! This story is actually a Fact!");
                $("#current_answer_fact").html("Fact: " + (((questions[questionCount][3])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                $("#current_answer_fiction").html("Fiction: " + (((questions[questionCount][4])/(questions[questionCount][3]+questions[questionCount][4]))*100).toFixed(2) + "%");
                questions[questionCount][3] = questions[questionCount][4]+1
            }
            $("#answer").show();
        });
        $("#game_next").click(function() {
            questionCount += 1;
            if(questionCount == questions.length){
                $("#your_answer").html("Thanks for playing!");
                $("#current_answer").html("You scored " + correctAnswer + " out of " + questions.length);
                $("#game_home").show();
                $("#game_fact").hide();
                $("#game_fiction").hide();
                $("#game_title").hide();
                $("#game_description").hide();
                $("#game_next").hide();
                $("#current_answer_fact").hide();
                $("#current_answer_fiction").hide();
                $("#game_or").hide();
            }
            else{
            $("#game_picture").attr('src', questions[questionCount][5]);
            $("#answer").hide();
            $("#game_picture").show();
            $("#game_title").html(questions[questionCount][0]);
            $("#game_description").html(questions[questionCount][1]);
            $("#game_fact").prop('disabled', false);
            $("#game_fiction").prop('disabled', false);
            }
        });
      });
```

population script:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'fact_or_fiction.settings')

import django
django.setup()
from factorfiction.models import Page, GameArticle

def populate():

    game_articles = [
        {"title":"Pope Francis Shocks World, Endorses Donald Trump for President, Releases Statement",
        "description":"News outlets around the world are reporting on the news that Pope Francis has made the unprecedented decision to endorse a US presidential candidate. His statement in support of Donald Trump was released from the Vatican this evening: 'I have been hesitant to offer any kind of support for either candidate in the US presidential election but I now feel that to not voice my concern would be a dereliction of my duty as the Holy See...",
        "answer":"fake",
        "fact": 7,
        "fiction": 15,
        "picture": "../../static/images/popetrump.jpg"},
        {"title":"Trump Offering Free One-Way Tickets to Africa & Mexico for Those Who Wanna Leave America",
        "description":"President elect Donald Trump has sensationally offered free one-way tickets to Mexico or Africa for anyone who wants to leave America in the aftermath of his election victory. The extraordinary, and highly controversial, offer was revealed by an aid at a press conference in New York this morning...",
        "answer":"fake",
        "fact": 13,
        "fiction": 17,
        "picture": "../../static/images/TrumpTickets.jpg"},
        {"title":"Feral pig drinks 18 cans of beer, fights cow and then passes out drunk under tree",
        "description":"The swine drank 18 beers on its bender in Port Hedland, Western Australia, according to ABC News. The alcohol also made the pig hungry and was seen looking through rubbish bags for something to eat...",
        "answer":"true",
        "fact": 8,
        "fiction": 19,
        "picture": "../../static/images/pig.jpg"},
        {"title":"Cinnamon Roll Can Explodes Inside Man's Butt During Shoplifting Incident",
        "description":"Las Vegas – Martin Klein, 41 of Las Vegas, was arrested after a shopping lifting incident turned horribly wrong. According to reports, Mr. Klein and his partner, Jerry Weis, had stolen several grocery items from the Las Vegas Walmart...",
        "answer":"fake",
        "fact": 19,
        "fiction": 7,
        "picture": "../../static/images/CinnamonRollMan.jpg"},
        {"title":"Poll: 38% of Florida voters believe Ted Cruz could be the Zodiac Killer",
        "description":"While a 62 percent majority of voters answered 'No' when asked if they believed Cruz was responsible for the string of murders in the early 70s, 10 percent answered 'Yes' and an additional 28 percent said they were unsure...",
        "answer":"true",
        "fact": 11,
        "fiction": 6,
        "picture": "../../static/images/FloridaPoll.jpg"},
        {"title":"Hamster resurrection: Pet rises from the grave at Easter after being buried in garden",
        "description":"Tink the hamster was found ‘cold and lifeless’ in the bottom of her cage and laid to rest by a couple who were looking after her for a friend. But the next day the rodent – who was not dead but hibernating – reappeared as perplexed Les Kilbourne-Smith crushed a pile of old boxes for recycling...",
        "answer":"true",
        "fact": 15,
        "fiction": 9,
        "picture": "../../static/images/hamster.jpg"}]

    for eachArticle in game_articles:
        add_game_article(eachArticle["title"], eachArticle["description"], eachArticle["picture"], eachArticle["answer"], eachArticle["fact"], eachArticle["fiction"])



def add_game_article(title,description,picture, answer, fact=0, fiction=0):
    games = GameArticle.objects.get_or_create(title=title)[0]
    games.description=description
    games.answer=answer
    games.fact=fact
    games.fiction=fiction
    games.picture=picture
    games.save()
    return games


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting FactOrFiction population script...")
    populate()
```

fofgame.html:

```
{% extends 'factorfiction/base.html' %}
    {% load staticfiles %}

    {% block title_block  %}
    FoF Game
    {% endblock %}


    {% block main_body_block %}
    <div class="current_article">
    <div class="row">
        <h1 id="game_title"></h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <p id="game_description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean 
        commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus 
        et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, 
        ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim.</p>
    </div>
        <button id="game_fact" type="button">Fact</button>
        <p id="game_or">OR</p>
        <button id="game_fiction" type="button">Fiction</button>
        <img id="game_picture" src='{% static "images/fakenews.jpg" %}' alt="Article Picture" />
        <div id="answer">
            <h1 id="your_answer"></h1>
            <p id="current_answer">Currently, other users have said:</p>
            <p id="current_answer_fact"></p>
            <p id="current_answer_fiction"></p>
            <button id="game_next" type="button">Next</button>
            <a href="{% url 'index' %}"><button id="game_home" type="button">Homepage</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of ajax-request. It fires when a button is clicked and makes a POST request to {% url "ajax_requests" %}. In success it loads some data on to a div... console.log() is used just for examine the returned data.

```
<script>
    $("#button1").click(function () {
     var itemid=1;

        $.ajaxSetup({
            data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
       });

       $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "ajax_requests" %}',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
          'item_id': itemid,
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          if (data) {
            console.log(data);

            html = '<img src="/user_images/' + data[6].fields.requesting_user[2] + ' "class="img-responsive" alt="Kuva">';
            $("#test").append(html);
          }
        }
      });

    });

  </script>
```

So to make this work you need to add a view and point to it from your_app/urls.py. Like this:

```
url(r'^ajax_requests/', ajaxrequests_view, name='ajax_requests'),
```

and in the views.py you query for the data, then serialize that to json and return:

```
def ajaxrequests_view(request):
    item_id = request.POST.get('item_id', None)
    get_data = MyModel.objects.select_related('item_owner').filter(item_id=item_id)
    ser_data = serializers.serialize("json", get_data)

    return HttpResponse(ser_data, content_type="application/json")
```